# Both HTTPS and HTTP on the same web application

Tags: https, iis-6

Windows Server 2003, IIS 6
We have an ASP.Net application, which is accessed using HTTP by customers.
Now one customer wants to access this application, using HTTPS (company security rules).
Can I set up IIS 6, so that I can satisfy both requirements? So that regardless of typing
http://www.foo.com/bar or https://www.foo.com/bar, the users will get the same experience? And those using HTTPS will continue using HTTPS during their ASP.Net session?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way for IIS6 to do http and https together in the same site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381991/is-there-a-way-for-iis6-to-do-http-and-https-together-in-the-same-site)

Comment: Note sure there is URL Rewrite for IIS 6, but have a look at http://urlrewriter.net/, URL Rewrite module helps to force Secured communication by rewriting or redirecting request.